# How to run multiple PHPUnit test suites from command line?

Tags: phpunit

If you have multiple test suites configured in `phpunit.xml` how do you run more than one test suite but not all of them from the command line?

*phpunit.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="true"
    syntaxCheck="true"
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
        <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="Unit">
                <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/unit</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Integration">
                <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/integration</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Acceptance">
                <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/acceptance</directory>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
        <logging>
            <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage"/>
            <log type="testdox-html" target="build/requirements.html"/>
        </logging>
        <filter>
            <whitelist>
                <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            </whitelist>
        </filter>
</phpunit>
```

*example*

`phpunit --testsuite Unit|Integration` but not `Acceptance`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since PHPUnit 6.0 you can specify a comma delimited list of suites:

```
--testsuite suite1,suite2
```

---

**Original answer for versions < PHPUnit 6.0**

It doesn't work as you expect it to i.e. (where `<pattern>` is not an actual pattern):

```
--testsuite <pattern> Filter which testsuite to run.
```

You can choose a test suite to run but you can't use a pattern to filter which ones to run.

A better description would be `--testsuite <name> Which testsuite to run.`

Issue report https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2273, which was [fixed](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/80754cf323fe96003a2567f5e57404fddecff3bf) in version 6.0.

Comment: actually the issue was solved (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/80754cf323fe96003a2567f5e57404fddecff3bf). and it now works by separating the testsuites with comma: `phpunit --testsuite suite1,suite2`